# Angular 2+: How to test host element styles that is applied through :host selector?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test styles applied on host element of a component but looks like the applied styles won't show up in `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.style` if they're applied through `:host` selector in stylesheet.

Let's say we have button component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and button.component.scss contains:

```
:host {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

and in our spec file:

```
describe('ButtonComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestApp>;
  let buttonDebugElement: DebugElement;
  let testComponent: TestApp;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ButtonModule],
      declarations: [TestApp],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestApp);
    testComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    buttonDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('test-button'));
  });

  describe('styles', () => {
    let hostElement: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
      hostElement = buttonDebugElement.nativeElement;
    });

    it('should have border-radius of 4px', () => {
      // hostElement.style.borderRadius is "" instead of "4px"
      expect(hostElement.style.borderRadius).toBe('4px');
    });
  });
});

/** Test App. */
@Component({
  selector: 'test-app',
  template: `
    <test-button>
      {{ textContent }}
    </test-button>
  `,
})
class TestApp {
  textContent: string = 'Hi test-button!';
}
```

But if I use `HostBinding('style.borderRadius')`, it works as expected.

Is there a way to test styles applied through :host selector? If none, is @HostBinding the only way to test styles applied on host element?

Comment: Per [view-encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation#inspecting-generated-css), the `:host` would be compiled to `[_nghost-xxx] {...}`. But somehow this is not true when testing. May need to check the implementation detail of `TestBed`.